# Android: An app failed to download/install - what do I do?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Sometimes I download an app but it fails to download or install. The message just says that, no further details. It generally seems that the app never installs after that. Is there anyway I can find out more details about why it failed? Is there any good way to get stuff to install after this has happened.

I am using Android 1.5 on a T-Mobile Pulse/Huawei U8220

Comment: Were you trying to download Talking Santa also?

Answer (score 3):

Can you get any app to install? First thing to always try is to reboot the phone.

If that doesnt work, try downloading aLogCat from the market (if you can install it). If it installs, then go to the market and try to download the app you're having issues with. If it STILL wont download, then open aLogCat and look at the system log entries. Then you should be able to glean a little bit of info of why its not installing. I know this is not a 100% answer of what you're looking for, but it does help and has helped me before.

Comment: I like the idea, but my phone seems to be stuck unable to install aLogCat :/ Can I view the logs any other way?

Comment: Using ADB, you can play with the logcat command.  Google around if you have no idea what that means, there are lots of instructions on how to set up ADB.

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to me there's one thing that helps every time:

Open the Market and go to the Downloads section, then perform a long click on the stalled download. Cancel the download from here. Now you should be able to reinstall / update the app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you out of internal storage for apps? Have you tried a hard reset? Can you upgrade your phone to a newer Android release? Personally I would try upgrading your device first then see if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Does the OS actually tell you it failed to download, or do you just notice? When i was running 2.0.1 i noticed a particular problem with trying to update/download multiple apps at once. If you are doing synchronous dls try one at a time.

Another option MAY be to try using Appbrain. It is an alternative installation app that hooks into market. (http://www.appbrain.com/)

Speaking of which, you could also try your QR reader and try to install via the internet using the programs' QR codes.