# App Installation Fails Every Time

Tags: google-play-store, 2.2-froyo, installation

My wife uses a Droid (first gen) running v2.2, and in the past month or so she can no longer download or update apps from the Market. We've tried rebooting the phone without any luck. The phone has internal storage available, so I don't believe that's an issue. Please help!

Comment: It would be helpful to know specifically is happening when she tries to dl or update an app. Does she get an error? Does it start and get stuck? Does nothing happen?

Comment: The phone can download the app just fine. It's always the installation that fails.

Comment: Maybe you also want to check the "Linked" section to the right? There are some matching Q&As like http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/682/android-an-app-failed-to-download-install-what-do-i-do / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/package-install-via-market-sometimes-fails-and-gives-seemingly-random-error-mess

Answer (score 2):

If she is rooted, try the following [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/installation-error).

Otherwise, does long pressing on the download --> cancel, then re-starting the install work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "long pressing on the download --> cancel" mean. (I'm not very familiar with Android, sorry).

Comment: Go to the Android market.  Go to the downloads screen.  Does it show that they are simply "downloading"?  If so, long press on on the item it is stuck on "downloading", then select cancel from the modal popup.  Then you can try to re-start the download.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/dropbox-always-downloading-on-htc-incredible/1519#1519

Comment: As I stated above, the phone can download the app just fine. It always errors when it tries to install it ("Installation unsuccessful).

Comment: Go through the app install process again.  When you click install/download it'll kick you back to the download screen.  Click on the app name again (while it is downloading and installing).  At the top of the screen it should list the install error code when it fails.  Please report back what the error code is.

Comment: When I install an app from the "Market" app, it doesn't take me to the download screen. It kicks me back to the home screen. I only know it's downloading/installing/failing via the notification area.

If I go back to the Market app and go to the download screen, when I click on the app, it pops open a menu that gives me two options: View Details or Cancel Download. View Details just takes me back to the Market page for the app.

Comment: @RHPT At the top of that screen, when the install fails, it should provide an error code right there.  If not, I'm not sure what else to suggest

Comment: I managed to successfully install aLog. Here's the log file with the error code highlighted: http://pastebin.com/c7H2rf5v

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install Angry Birds.  Do you have sufficient free space on your phone?

Comment: It's not just Angry Birds though. The phone has plenty of space. Here's another log when some apps installed OK, while others failed. http://pastebin.com/mcE58K6Z

Comment: It might be because those apps are trying to default install to the SD card.  See this XDA post: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=753437  It does indeed look like the install failure is the same as mine.  "Unknown reason -18"

Comment: I've also found the need to Cancel the download, then restart the phone, then start the install again. In some cases, I had to uninstall the app and then reinstall to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails do a factory reset: http://www.ehow.com/i/#article_5634169