# Package file is invalid

Tags: applications, google-play-store, system-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Package Install via Market sometimes fails and gives seemingly random error message](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/package-install-via-market-sometimes-fails-and-gives-seemingly-random-error-mess)

Whenever I try and download an app from the Google Play Store, or update an existing app, I get the following error message appear:

> Package file is invalid

Which is this, and what can I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Whenever I have an android issue (as rare as it is) I find it helps to locate the nearest iPhone and smash the crap out of it. Then I have a clear mind in order to do some vital Google searching. Hope that helps ;) Also, I would be very interested in finding the solution to this too

Comment: Does this happen for apps that you do not have a previous version installed on? Can you try with an apk that doesn't come from the market? (i.e. [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner4.2.apk&can=2&q=))? And lastly this may sound strange but is the date on your device set manually or auto? and if manual is it set far into the future or past or inline with the current date?

Comment: How much free space do you have (on each partition)?  Have you tried clearing the data for the Play Store app?

Comment: Just take a look at the question [Package Install via Market sometimes fails and gives seemingly random error message](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/package-install-via-market-sometimes-fails-and-gives-seemingly-random-error-mess?rq=1) -- your question is covered there as well.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for finding that, if it solves Curt's problem I think we will close as duplicate.

Comment: @MatthewRead was not hard to find: just take a look at the "Related" section to the right :)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for your reply. While waiting for answers from this question I did some more research online, which led me to delete my Google Play Store application, and now I can't reinstall it :/ http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26310/ive-deleted-google-play-store-how-can-i-reinstall-it

Comment: @Curt that was a really bad idea -- and I could think of nothing where that could have helped. But that's a complete new question then; go ahead and create a new one, include information on how you deleted the app, and whether your device is rooted (I assume it is, or you would not have been able to delete it).

Comment: I'm going to close this as a duplicate for now, largely for the benefit of future readers, since the answer in the linked question does address the error you're seeing. If you can get the Play Store re-installed and find that the duplicate is not useful then we can certainly take another look at re-opening this as a separate question.