# Package file is invalid

Tags: google-play-store, htc-desire, downloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Package Install via Market sometimes fails and gives seemingly random error message](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/package-install-via-market-sometimes-fails-and-gives-seemingly-random-error-mess)

Every time i try to download a app from the android market place to my HTC desire it will download the app but wont install it, I've tried clearing the cache and data from the Market place and Download Manager. Nothing seems to be working does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15932/ But I don't think that this should be closed as a duplicate. IMHO the error is pretty common. I experienced it myself, but IIRC it did go away after a short time.

Comment: Maybe you check the question Flow mentioned. If that does not solve your problem, please update your question with some additional facts: Does it only happen for a specific app, some apps, or generally and for all apps? This does not get really clear currently.

Comment: See also: [Package file is invalid](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26170/) and [Server Error! Play Store failing](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27859/). @Flow taking a look at the second one, I'd consider it a clear duplicate (though the question phrasing does not make it clear, the answer 100% does)